# Type: PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception Message: internal error

Tags: php, phpexcel, slim

> Hi, I want to add a graph and I miss this error when trying
>
> Type: PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception
>   Message: internal error
>   File: C:\xampp\htdocs\php-excel-inf-graf\vendor\phpoffice\phpexcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Calculation.php
>   Line: 3734

A summary of my code:

```
    public function addChart1($objPHPExcel)
    {
        $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndexByName('Graficos');

$dataseriesLabels1 = [
            new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String','SMS Certificado Totales!$F$6',NULL, 1),
        ];

    $xAxisTickValues = [

        new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String','SMS Certificado Totales!$B$6:$B$11',NULL, 6),
    ];

    $dataSeriesValues1 = [
        new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'SMS Certificado Totales!$F$8:$F$11', NULL, 4),       
    ];

    $series1 = new PHPExcel_Chart_Dataseries(
      PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_LINECHART,
      PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_STANDARD,
      range(0,count($dataSeriesValues1)-1),
      $dataseriesLabels1,
      $xAxisTickValues,
      $dataSeriesValues1
    );

    $series1->setPlotDirection(PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::DIRECTION_COL);

 $plotarea = new PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea(NULL, array($series1));
   $legend = new PHPExcel_Chart_Legend(PHPExcel_Chart_Legend::POSITION_RIGHT, NULL, false);
        $title = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Mi primer Chart');
$chart = new PHPExcel_Chart(
            'chart1',       // name
            $title,     // title
            $legend,        // legend
            $plotarea,      // plotArea
            true,           // plotVisibleOnly
            0,              // displayBlanksAs
            NULL,           // xAxisLabel
            NULL    // yAxisLabel
        );
   $chart->setTopLeftPosition('A7');
   $chart->setBottomRightPosition('H20');
   $objWorksheet->addChart($chart);
}
```

Then I do the `$objWriter-> setIncludeCharts (TRUE)`; in another file

Regards

EDIT: code in the line 3734:

```
// trigger an error, but nicely, if need be
    protected function _raiseFormulaError($errorMessage) {
        $this->formulaError = $errorMessage;
        $this->_cyclicReferenceStack->clear();
3734    if (!$this->suppressFormulaErrors) throw new PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception($errorMessage);
        trigger_error($errorMessage, E_USER_ERROR);
    }   //  function _raiseFormulaError()
```

Comment: what is line 3734?  Error message would indicate to start looking there

Comment: Hi, now I get another error
Type: PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception
Message: internal error
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\php-excel-inf-graf\vendor\phpoffice\phpexcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Calculation.php
Line: 3734

Comment: in the same line. 
I edit, the question with line 3734

Comment: from the code it would appear there is a formula error in the Excel sheet and the code is throwing a formula error exception.

Comment: I know.. but..
I have removed all the formulas, and I have added numbers, and the same error is returned to me

Comment: Ok...Now it works for me, but with formulas it does not work for me, ... the formulas are in Spanish pff ....